# Alternative postmaster address if first fails

Tags: email, postfix

I am using postfix to send status reports about my server to an external email address. If the delivery fails the postmaster is informed. It's address is defined in /etc/aliases with something like

postmaster: me@example.com

Is it possible to provide a second email address (like me@otherexample.com) which would be used in case the delivery to me@example.com fails for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just write

`postmaster: one@one.example, two@two.example`

See `aliases(5)` manpage.

I just recommend to have one address local stored: if postfix has problem, it could also not send mails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that now if both one@one.example, two@two.example are wokring addresses, both get the mail. I would like one@one.example to be used as postmaster and only if the delivery fails to one@one.example for some reason, then send the mail to two@two.example.